# Saving imported excel data in a datagrid to sqlite database

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, sqlite

I'm trying to save the data I have imported from excel into my datagrid to my database.

Data base details:

- File - tensiondata.db
- Table - data

I can't find enough information on how to perform this, I've attached the code below. I'm not even certain that saving it to a database is the right solution. Is there a way you can save the datagrid somewhere else?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Open Excel File for Tension, Velocity or Takeup" Height="550" Width="900">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="Capture.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="68" Margin="5,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75"/>
        <GroupBox x:Name="Options" Header="Options" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="85,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="562">
        </GroupBox>
        <Button x:Name="save_file" Content="Save and Update" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="451,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176" Height="40" Click="Button_Click_1" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Button Content="Generate Graph" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,463,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" Height="29" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFilePath" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="189,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233"/>
        <Button Content="Search" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,32,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" Height="24" x:Name="search_file" Click="Open_Click"/>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dtGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="356" Margin="37,83,44,80" Width="811" RenderTransformOrigin="0.529,0.503" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class Window3 : Window
{
    string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source = tensiondata.db;Version=3;"; // String connection 
    private object con;

    public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Opening Excel file into data grid 
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
        openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        //openfile.ShowDialog();
        var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();
        if (browsefile == true)
        {
            txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text.ToString(), 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;
            string strCellData = "";
            double douCellData;
            int rowCnt = 0;
            int colCnt = 0;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
            {
                string strColumn = "";
                strColumn = (string)(excelRange.Cells[1, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                dt.Columns.Add(strColumn, typeof(string));
            }
            for (rowCnt = 1; rowCnt <= excelRange.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
            {
                string strData = "";
                for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        strCellData = (string)(excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                            strData += strCellData + "|";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        douCellData = (excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        strData += douCellData.ToString() + "|";
                    }
                }
                strData = strData.Remove(strData.Length - 1, 1);
                dt.Rows.Add(strData.Split('|'));
            }
            dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Next Window Button 
    {
        Window2 sec = new Window2();
        sec.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Save and update button
    {
        //Open connection to database
        SQLiteConnection SQLiteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        SQLiteCon.Open();
        try
        {
        }
        //SQLiteCon.Close();
        //}
        // while (dr.Read())
        // {
        //  }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you export your spreadsheet as a CSV file? https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv_import

Comment: I don't think I need to. I'm importing a large set of data from excel into a datagrid in window 3, then I need to store the data from the data grid somewhere (I thought a database would be best) to then produce a live chart in window 2.

Answer (score 0):

Like other DB, SQLite need to design it's Table structure before you insert record into it.
I suggest you to read document of SQLite.It will be usefull.

And DataTable is available as a data source.